# Pointer to the method / passing this pointer / boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, this, bind

I'm wondering how "this" pointer is being passed to the methods from the class.
Let's see this snippet of code:

```
class CTest
{
public:
    CTest(int n_) : n(n_) {}
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    CTest t1(100);

    boost::bind(&CTest::method, &t1)(); //100
    boost::bind(&CTest::method, _1)(&t1); //100
    Test::method(&t1); //no matching function for call to ‘CTest::method(CTest*)’

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming the bind works just like a function object, it passes this/object pointer somehow. If I want to do it explicitly I get an compilation error.

How does it work in fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::bind` recognises when the target it wraps is a pointer to member, and uses a different code path that calls it using the right syntax for a pointer to member.

Like most problems in programming, you can solve it by adding a level of indirection. `bind` can apply a transformation to its target so that a pointer to member will be adapted into something that can be called like a normal function object, and takes care of the details, so `bind` itself doesn't need to know the details.

The function `boost::mem_fn` can be used to transform a pointer to member into a callable object:

```
void (CTest::*memptr)() = &CTest::method;
CTest* p = &t1;
auto callable = boost::mem_fn(memptr);
callable(p);  // calls (p.->*memptr)()
```

So given that adaptor, `bind` only needs to ensure it is used whenever needed.

In the GCC implementation we have something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct maybe_wrap_mem_ptr
{
  typedef T type;
};

// partial specialization for pointer to member
template<class R, class C>
struct maybe_wrap_mem_ptr<R C::*>
{
  typedef mem_fn_wrapper<R C::*> type;
};

template<class T>
typename maybe_wrap_mem_ptr<T>::type
wrap_mem_ptr(T t)
{ return typename maybe_wrap_mem_ptr<T>::type(t); }
```

Where `mem_fn_wrapper` is the type returned by the `std::mem_fn` function. So `bind` can just use `wrap_mem_ptr` to ensure that the object it wraps can be called uniformly.